# How does the syntax work for a pointer variable of a pointer object?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

When accessing a pointer variable of a pointer object, how does the syntax work? Do I need two `*`?

Here's an example to explain my situation better:

```
void function(ofObject *object)  //passing by ref so that I can change it
{
int n;
n=*object.*x;  //object is a pointer, but so is the class member x;
}
```

If I just put the `*` at the beginning, then `*object.x` would simply return the address of `object.x`, wouldn't it? Or would it? Am I just overthinking this?

Comment: `*object->x`, or `*(*object).x`.  The `->` and `.` bind more tightly than `*` so you do not need extra parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` operator has lower precedence than the `.` operator, so `*object.x` will be a compiler error since it's the same as `*(object.x)`.  This is what the `->` operator exists for.  `object->x` is the same as `(*object).x`.  If `ofObject::x` is a pointer, you can then dereference it using the `*` operator as normal.  So putting it all together, to dereference a pointer member through a pointer, you can use `*object->x`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped clear up my confusion on object pointers in general.

Answer (score 0):

use () to help reduce confusion or make access methods
if you want the value of x, *(object->x), or *((*object).x)
but if you make access methods you can call object->getx(); where getx() returns value of x

Answer (score 0):

For any pointer if you wants to deference it use `*` and as `*` is has lower precedence than `.` It will be useful if you're using `()` to mark execution preference.

```
*((*object).x)
*object->x    (I will recommend this).
```